# Duplicate results in twig Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

When i try to print my data in twig template like :

```
{% for entity in entities %} {{ entity.name }} {% endfor %}
```

I get this result :

```
apple , orange , apple
```

I want to filter duplicate result like :

```
apple , orange
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicated items in array on Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788424/how-to-remove-duplicated-items-in-array-on-twig)

Comment: do it in your sql query, not in the view!

Answer (score -1):

Write your own **[Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)** using function **[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)**