# Remove item from associative array using twig template engine

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to remove an item form associative array within twig page.

Knowing that I have already the key of the item such as "key1"

Comment: You don't really want to do this, as Twig should just be displaying the data, and you should be preparing it in Symfony before it ever gets to Twig.  That being said, it's still possible by making your own custom Twig function which is described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26543511/1307183

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicated items in array on Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788424/how-to-remove-duplicated-items-in-array-on-twig)

Comment: thx a lot, yes i'ts the solution