# Twig Check if string in multidimensional array exist

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, twig, symfony

I have a multidimensional array and want to check if a string exist in the arrays.

But I don't want that if the string exist multiple times, that the button shown multiple times.

```
{% for city in all if city.city == "Hamburg"%}
   {# Should show button only once #}
    <button>Hamburg</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Now it returns Hamburg Hamburg Hamburg Hamburg Hamburg Hamburg...
I only want that the Button is shown only once.

Hope my Question is clear and please can you guys help me, I have no idea how to go on.

Comment: [Remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788424/how-to-remove-duplicated-items-in-array-on-twig#17796120) and then go through the loop?

Comment: Not possible. There are profiles with cities. At example 50 profiles with city Hamburg, 30 profiles with city Berlin and so on. And the button should use at quick link for search. The profiles change daily so I can't create buttons manually. Sometimes there is no profile with city Hamburg

Comment: I don't understand. You should be able to make a second array `all_unique` where there are no duplicates and which can be used for this loop

Comment: ^ If you have created the unique array you don't need to loop the array the to test if an element is inside the element, you just use the `in` test : `{% if 'hamburg' in uniq_countries %}`

Comment: I think i know what you mean guys, but I curl the profiles from an Api. I cant create new array (or I dont know how).
`
Array:4[
      profiles => Array[
           1=> Array[
               "ID" => 1234
               "City" => "Hamburg"
               ]
      ]
   "Someelse Array => Array[]
]

And so one..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3U7khp0P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DarkBee

I have an extra php file for api requests

```
function getCities() {
    $cities=api();
    if(!is_array($cities)) $cities=[];
    foreach($cities as $city)
        if (!in_array($city['city'], $cities)) $cities[] = $city['city'];
        sort($cities);
        return $cities;
}
```

Render it in Controller

```
return $this->render('template.html.twig', [
        'Cities'=>$this->getCities(),
    ]);
```

And finally in template

```
{% if "Hamburg" in Cities %}
                Hamburg
            {% endif %}
```