# Check if data is the same as previous

Tags: twig

I want to know if it's possible to look at what Twig "print" before something coming. Let me explain. I generate a list like :

**Actual case :**

- Item 1

  - Item 2
- Item 3

  - Item 4
- Item 5

  - Item 6
- ...

It might be possible that "Item 5" === "Item 1" (for exemple), and I don't want to print the same value twice. I want something like that :

- Item 1

  - Item 2
  - Item 6
- Item 3

  - Item 4
- ...

If we take the actual case, it may be possible that "Item 2" === "Item 4", for exemple, and I want :

- Item 1
- Item 3

  - Item 2
- Item 5

  - Item 6
- ...

Here my Twig code :

```
{% for underActivity in activity.underActivities %}
    {% for indice in underActivity.indications %}
        {% for adjusting in indice.adjustings %}
           {% if adjusting is not null %}
               <li>{{adjusting.name}}
                   <ul>
                       {% if indice.indicationPostAdjusting == "Green" %}
                           <li class="text-success">{{underActivity.name}}</li>
                       {% elseif indice.indicationPostAdjusting == "Orange" %}    
                           <li class="text-warning">{{underActivity.name}}</li>
                       {% else %}
                           <li class="text-danger">{{underActivity.name}}</li>
                       {% endif %}
                   </ul>
               </li>
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>Aucun aménagement n a été trouvée.</p>
{% endfor %}
   ...
```

Do you have any ideas ?

**-- UPDATE --**

I have this :

[image]

and I want this :

- Travailler en binôme

  - Toquer à la porte
  - Signaler la présence dans la chambre

And :

- Surélever la table
- Ouverture automatique

  - Ouvrir les volets

**To have something like that, at the final** :

- Travailler en binôme

  - Toquer à la porte
  - Signaler la présence dans la chambre
- Surélever la table
- Ouverture automatique

  - Ouvrir les volets

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

I've tried to create the array with datas that I want. Here is my code inside my controller :

```
foreach ($indications as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $indication) {
        $datas[] = [
            "adjusting" => $indication->getAdjustings(),
            "underActivity" => $indication->getUnderActivities(),
        ];

    }
}
```

And that's what I got :

[image]

So now, how can I have the "name" of adjusting and underActivity ? because the "getName()" function doesn't work ? And that's what you want to see ?

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788424/how-to-remove-duplicated-items-in-array-on-twig).

Comment: @MohammadSalehi thanks ! it works ! But in my case the "Item 1" === "Item 5" and it doesn't print the "Item 6". How can I render it below the "Item 2" ?

Comment: @DarkBee because, in my opinion, it's easier to do that in Twig... idk

Comment: No, it's not. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401743/reorganize-array-in-twig/72405741#72405741) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57473184/446594) for similar questions. The twig code just looks awfull to comprehend. But it could be usefull as well for your question if you really want to do it inside the template

Comment: @DarkBee I understand the first one better, but I don't know how to adapt it to my code. The "category" would be my "adjusting.name" and "name" would be my "underActivity.name". What bothers me the most, it's the "object" part...

Comment: `item` should not be `adjusting` ?

Comment: I guess, yes ! (I understand) So it would look like my UPD above ?

Comment: where do I need to make it ?

Comment: and what would these two loops look like ?

Comment: I've updated :)

Comment: Please do like a `var_dump`...

Comment: of what ? i don't understand 

Comment: Hello @DarkBee ! I've updated my question. Can you check it when you got time pls